# Pandas - Reshape with delimited values (reverse melt)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I'm new to Pandas (started this week) and I'm at the final step of my script and I'm stuck. I need to roll up the data I melted into separated values while maintaining the key.

I have a data frame that currently looks as follows:

```
Index,ID#,Start Page, End Page
0, 1, Page 1, Page5
1, 2, Page 10, Page 20
2, 2, Page 25, Page 30
```

Index is the default dataframe index. ID# is my key.

I'm trying to this result:

```
ID#,Start Page, End Page
1, Page 1, Page 5
2, Page 10; Page 25, Page 20; Page 30
```

I'm trying to roll this upward where the starting pages are delimited together (semicolon in this example) as well as the ending pages.

I'm using Jupyter Notebooks (python 3) with the pandas library.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `groupby.agg`:

```
# chain with to_csv() if needed
df.groupby('ID#', as_index=False)[['Start Page', 'End Page']].agg('; '.join)
```

Or since you mentioned *reverse melt*, albeit a little slower, `pivot_table`:

```
(df.pivot_table(index=['ID#'], 
               values=['Start Page', 'End Page'], 
               aggfunc='; '.join)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   ID#        Start Page          End Page
0    1            Page 1             Page5
1    2  Page 10; Page 25  Page 20; Page 30
```